# unable to decode base64 string from email raw data

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to decode a base64 string from a text file that has raw email conversations.
I have tried everything but nothing works.. 
The text file starts as given below, also included the base64 string in it:

```
 {"headers":
    {"Mime-Version":
    "1.0
    (1.0)",
    "Dkim-Signature":
    "v=1;
    a=rsa-sha256;
    c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=yahoo.com;
    s=s2048;
    t=1524075605;
    bh=aQqYfuYOtkQGrUPknrAaTe+SXDgSzNg2EHOkruCuE38=;
    h=From:Date:Subject:References:In-Reply-To:To:From:Subject;
b=Yis3dAX8CR9v2GKUisIGuQ2Ez0LKM2h1QgYx8B/7Z19xu7clNWgdYXjru13dMe99fizEZfKMh5dJU6fhPMMoOmw6S9YQjpuABU5yBBgfy2tMbxJ9C3OiYO+4KAPXw16Bm9eshX2gDy042BpMAIvU9SDE6B5eG3onTtSzqqdmgNa8tZnW6M3RKmUUFsBVjZkJfFWsbq2bqS+9z3JK3Bi7E+9RHUf7RbO2b6FU9JR0aOn1zgQwC890+OuFaD+7FEBdSewCS8FrumCy81Gow7zy9EuSWMkFtxjqkN/1oWO5pBMCCuAztu+z+lqDNwa0Mqk3VVbbfTR9N6sDHsyqhDzh4w==",
    "To": .........
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, May this help you

```
import base64
encodedString = "YOUR_STRING_HERE"
base64.b64decode(encodedString)
```

Comment: Thanks.. i tried, it doesnt work.. It gave me this output:

Comment: b"m\x88\xac\xdd\xd0\x17\xf0$}\xbfa\x8aR+\x08\x1a\xe46\x13=\x0b(\xcd\xa1\xd5\x08\x18\xc7\xc0{g_q\xbb\xb7%5h\x1dax\xeb\xbb]\xdd1\xef}~,\xc4e\xf2\x8c\x87\x97IS\xa7\xe1<\xc3(:l:K\xd6\x10\x8e\x9b\x80\x05Nr\x04\x18\x1f\xcbkLo\x12}\x0bs\xa2`\xef\xb8(\x03\xd7\xc3^\x81\x9b\xd7\xac\x85}\xa0\x0f-8\xd8\x1aL\x00\x8b\xd4\xf5 \xc4\xe8\x1e^\x1bz'N\xd4\xb3\xaa\xa7f\x80\xd6\xbc\xb5\x99\xd6\xe8\xcd\xd1*e\x14\x16\xc0U\x8d\x99\t|U\xacn\xad\x9b\xa9/\xbd\xcfrJ\xdc\x18\xbb\x13\xefQ\x1dG\xfbE\xb3\xb6o\xa1T\xf4\x94th\xe9\xf5\xce\x040\x0b\xcft\xf8\xeb\x85h?\xbb\x14@

Comment: continuing output: ]I\xec\x02K\xc1k\xba`\xb2\xf3Q\xa8\xc3\xbc\xf2\xf4K\x92X\xc9\x05\xb7\x18\xea\x90\xdf\xf5\xa1c\xb9\xa4\x13\x02\n\xe03\xb6\xef\xb3\xfaZ\x837\x06\xb42\xa97UV\xdb}4}7\xab\x03\x1e\xcc\xaa\x84<\xe1\xe3" Tried saving this op as image file but displays nothing.. @KeshavGarg

Comment: @Rucha can you please specify the string that you want to decode?

Comment: sure..from the eamil data mentioned in the main question,i believe given below is the base64 string..

Comment: b=Yis3dAX8CR9v2GKUisIGuQ2Ez0LKM2h1QgYx8B/7Z19xu7clNWgdYXjru13dMe99fizEZfKMh5dJU6fhPMMoOmw6S9YQjpuABU5yBBgfy2tMbxJ9C3OiYO+4KAPXw16Bm9eshX2gDy042BpMAIvU9SDE6B5eG3onTtSzqqdmgNa8tZnW6M3RKmUUFsBVjZkJfFWsbq2bqS+9z3JK3Bi7E+9RHUf7RbO2b6FU9JR0aOn1zgQwC890+OuFaD+7FEBdSewCS8FrumCy81Gow7zy9EuSWMkFtxjqkN/1oWO5pBMCCuAztu+z+lqDNwa0Mqk3VVbbfTR9N6sDHsyqhDzh4w==  @KeshavGarg

Comment: @Rucha This value refers to a digital signature value which is encoded in other format by Google not in base64 format. refer this [link](http://dkim.org/specs/rfc4871-dkimbase.html). So i guess it's not possible to decode using base64 decoding function because also a bytes array is decoded and we are giving a string as an input

Comment: The value followed by `b=` is a digital signature value

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look into it further